# Formulating a function.Trying to understand normal distribution.

Tags: normal-distribution

How would a person go about formulating the normal distribution function satisfying the following conditions, for the first time ever? 
The conditions are 
      
 1)The function must be defined for all real number 
       
2)The function's output value at any point must lie between zero and 1 i.e. (0,1) 
       
3)The total area under the graph of the function must be equal to one. 
       
4)The output value decreases as we move away from a point 'A' in the input. 
  
Please give step by step instructions if possible. I am trying to understand how normal distribution function was formulated from these conditions.

Comment: There are many distributions which have these characteristics.

Comment: @David Peterson Ok. Thank you for answering. But I am only interested in the normal distribution function i.e. how to formulate it from these conditions. I have edited the question.

Comment: My point is, those conditions alone do not define a normal distribution.

Comment: @David Peterson Please edit the question to add the other conditions needed for the normal distribution. I am just interested in understanding how normal distribution was formulated from the conditions needed to define the probability of a continuous random variable (not sure whether this is the right term).

Comment: One way the normal distribution can be discovered is as an approximation to the binomial distribution when $n$ (the number of independent Bernoulli trials) is large.

Comment: @littleO I tried it(I was following the Khan academy videos on probability)  but couldn't understand it.